# Session goes break in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a form in `codeigniter`. This form is displayed after login. When I fill form with upload an Image then my codeigniter site break session and goes to login form. But if I submit form without file uploading then this work fine. Please help me.

EDITED....

```
        $result = $this->addcategory->addcategory($add_cat); //Save the data
        if($result > 0){ //Check last inserted id
            if(!empty($_FILES['HM_cat_image']['name'])){ //check file upload or not
                $time = time();
                $upImage = uploadImage($_FILES['HM_cat_image'],$time); //Helper function to upload image in folder
                if($upImage == 1){ // if file upload then return 1
                    $catImage = $time . '_' . $_FILES['HM_cat_image']['name'];
                    $catImageData = array('category_id' => $result,'image' => $catImage);
                    $imgRes = $this->addcategory->addCategoryImage($catImageData); // Save image in database
                    if($imgRes > 0){
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Information Has been Successfully Saved');
                    }else{
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Information Has been Successfully Saved But Error In Image Saving.');
                    }
                }else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Information Has been Successfully Saved But Error In Image Upload.');
                }
            }else{
            //$data['formMsg'] = 'Data Saved Successfully.';
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Information Has been Successfully Saved');
            }
            redirect('folder/controller/allCategory','refresh');
        }
```

New Edited........

`When I upload small Images then this issue not come but when I try to upload large image like 450X250 or large then this issue come.`

Comment: Please check the code. I have edited my question

Comment: I have added session library $this->load->library('session'); inside __construct()

Answer (score 0):

check the following points, hope this will help.

1. set your CI encryption_key into 'application/config.php' to use session.
2. load session library
3. check your form is set to accept 'multipart'.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your session is created, add this code on your login controller

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(true);
```

search and find your session you want in session section on output from codeigniter profiler.

or you can save session on your database, use

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

and setup that